# Web API and XML

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am doing my first experiments with the Web API and I am finding particularly cumbersome to work with XML. Apparently, anything can be serialized in nice JSON, but weird things happen when you try to do the same in XML. Generics, arrays, anonymous objects and I think even dynamics get serialized nicely. But try to serialize a generic object in XML... and it does not work.

Is there any third party XML serializer I can use that does not need attributes to perform serialization? Or any where I can use the same attributes for JSON and XML. I have used Newton JSON before for JSON serialization with excellent results, and I was wondering if anything like that exists for XML.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Vtorola, you can use this solution that I created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951521/web-api-dynamic-to-xml-serialization/19085236#19085236